# Calling proc within a tcl thread

Tags: multithreading, tcl, proc

When I try to call a proc within a tcl thread, I get an error stating invalid command name. Following is my tcl code. Pls help in identifying why the proc is not recognized within the thread. Thanks.

```
package require Thread

proc CPUload { Start Stop } {
    for {set i $Start} {$i <= $Stop} {incr i} { 
        set j [expr {sqrt($i)*sqrt($i)}] 
        set k [expr {$i % 123}] 
    } 
}

set id1 [thread::create]

catch {thread::send $id1 "CPUload 1 50000000"} ret

puts $ret
puts $errorInfo

while {[llength [thread::names]] > 1} {
    after 500
}
```

Error msg is as follows

```
invalid command name "CPUload"
    while executing
"CPUload 1 50000000"
    invoked from within
"thread::send $id1 "CPUload 1 50000000""
```

Comment: Read the Threading docs... You need to load/initialize your procs in the threads, they are not shared automatically/magically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tcl threads are much more strongly independent from each other than in many other programming languages. Each has its own interpreter, a totally different context with its own commands (and procedures) and “global” variables. You need to create your procedures in the other thread.

However, it turns out to be pretty simple.

```
set id1 [thread::create]
thread::send $id1 {
    proc CPUload { Start Stop } {
        for {set i $Start} {$i <= $Stop} {incr i} { 
            set j [expr {sqrt($i)*sqrt($i)}] 
            set k [expr {$i % 123}] 
        } 
    }
}
```

You also probably want to use the `-async` option to the heavy load call so that you don't suspend the origin thread waiting for things to finish.

```
thread::send -async $id1 "CPUload 1 50000000"
```

You may want to adjust your code so that the worker thread sends a message back to the origin thread when the processing is done. How to do that is out of the scope of your particular question though.