# TCL: thread::send command is running in main thread instead of thread id mentioned in send command

Tags: multithreading, tcl, send

Below is the example script written for implementing multi threading for my existing single (main thread) threaded scripts.

```
# Wrapper proc for executing passed procedure list
proc eval_procs {dut_no procList} {
telnet_dut $dut_no ;# proc to change telnet id to $dut_no
puts "thread id: [thread::id]"
foreach procedure [join [list $procList]] {
    eval [join $procedure]
  }
}

for {set i 0} {$i <= 1} {incr i} {            
lappend jointhreadIds [thread::create]            
}

set dutList [list 1 2]
set dutConfigList [list [list "get_port_statistics_mt 1"] [list "c_get_port_statistics_mt 2"]] ;#proc for getting port statistics from switch 1 and 2

for {set i 0} {$i <= 1} {incr i} {            
thread::send -async [lindex $jointhreadIds $i] [eval_procs [lindex $dutList $i] [lindex $dutConfigList $i]]             
}
```

Two threads are created for calling the same proc (eval_procs) for each switch. But, when the proc is called using the thread::send -async, this proc is called sequentially for switch1 and later for switch2. After printing thread::id in eval_procs, I found that these procs are running in main thread, which is the reason for sequential run.

Any one to help me here, what mistake I am doing here or any other procedure to follow ?

The below post mentions to define the procs in the script while creating thread, but for me I have so many already developed libraries (procs) which are working fine with main thread. So, I can not move all the libraries under the thread::create.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32154589/13100284

Answer (score 1):

In general, any custom procedures (or C commands) you create in your master interpreter are *not* also created in the interpreters of other threads. You can use the [`ttrace` system](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/ThreadCmd/ttrace.htm) of the Thread package to do the replication, but you'll need to explicitly load any extra C commands you need. (I prefer to just put everything required in packages and then just `package require` in every worker thread as required, but that's more complex.)

```
package require Ttrace

# Procedures created in here get replicated to current and future threads
ttrace::eval {
    # Wrapper proc for executing passed procedure list
    proc eval_procs {dut_no procList} {
        telnet_dut $dut_no ;# proc to change telnet id to $dut_no
        puts "thread id: [thread::id]"
        foreach procedure [join [list $procList]] {
            eval [join $procedure]
        }
    }
    # You probably need to create the other commands here; I don't know your code, but you can source them just fine
}

# Now, the rest of your code as normal.
for {set i 0} {$i <= 1} {incr i} {
    lappend jointhreadIds [thread::create]
}

set dutList [list 1 2]
set dutConfigList [list [list "get_port_statistics_mt 1"] [list "c_get_port_statistics_mt 2"]]; #proc for getting port statistics from switch 1 and 2

for {set i 0} {$i <= 1} {incr i} {
    thread::send -async [lindex $jointhreadIds $i] [eval_procs [lindex $dutList $i] [lindex $dutConfigList $i]]
}
```

Note that you probably have other bugs too. And that last command offends me, as it should be using a multi-list `foreach` and building the command to go to to the other thread with `list`. Here, I mean it should be something like this:

```
foreach  t_id $joinThreadIds  dut_no $dutList  dut_config $dutConfigList  {
    # I've split the next line in two for even more clarity
    thread::send -async $t_id [list \
            eval_procs $dut_no $dut_config]
}
```

Comment: If he's using `thread::send -async`, shouldn't he be creating the threads with `thread::create -joinable {thread::wait}` ??

Comment: @glennjackman: if no script is specified in the `thread::create` command, it effectively does a `thread::wait`. The -joinable option should not be used unless you are going to do a `thread::join` later. So just using `thread::create` is fine in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing `eval_procs` in the current thread and sending the **result** to the threads to execute. Since `eval_procs` returns the empty string, the threads effectively do nothing.

You probably want an additional `list` in there:

```
thread::send -async [lindex $jointhreadIds $i] \
  [list eval_procs [lindex $dutList $i] [lindex $dutConfigList $i]]
```

But that will fail, because the `eval_procs` command is not known in the worker threads. You will have to define that proc in each of the subthreads, rather than in the current one.

Comment: After defining the `eval_procs` inside the thread creation, the script aborts with reason **Invalid command name `get_port_statistics_mt`** since `get_port_statistics_mt` proc is defined another library file.

Comment: As I indicated, the command you execute in the thread has to be available there. If you replace `eval_procs` with something else, then you have to make sure that command exists.